# Alternative for toJSON method in Ember 1.0.0-RC.1

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the latest emberjs release, toJSON method is no longer supported in the Ember Objects and DS. Is there any alternative to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's what serializers were implemented for.

```
var serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.create();
var post = App.Post.find(1);
var json = serializer.serialize(post);
```

The philosophy is that the serialization method should be independent of the model, since it varies depending on the choice of adapter. You just need to instantiate the one you want, and then you can apply it as needed.

Comment: This also available directly on the model. `var post = App.Post.find(1); post.serialize();`
Serializers belong to Adapters, and each model class has an adapter assigned on initialization, accessible via `store.adapterForType(App.Post)`.
By default it is the adapter provided when initializing your Store, but it can be overridden via `App.Store.registerAdapter("App.Post", myCustomAdapter)`.

Comment: Thanks its make sense now.